# flask don't show table content while preview does

Tags: flask, jinja2

code is:

```
def get_case():
    ...
    table_step = zip(li_host,li_cmd)
    return render_template('auto.html',table_step = table_step)
```

html is:

```
{% for row in table_step %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ row[0]|safe }}</td>
  <td>{{ row[1]|safe }}</td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> 编辑 </button></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

actual page shows no content:

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is no items in `table_step`.

Comment: table_step do have value:[('10.1.1.1:33333', "u'a': 1, u'b': 2"), ('10.1.1.1:33333', "u'a': 1, u'b': 2")]